# Yii2: Am I able to use multiple models in a search model?

Tags: yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-active-records

In Yii2, am I able to include two models (active records) in one search model and display them in a gridview?

For example, I have two tables, "**customers**", and "**customer_contacts**".

In my search model I am using **Customers** as my main model, while I wish to "left join" to **CustomerContacts**, and eventually display the **Customers.name** and **CustomerContacts.phoneNumber** in the gridview (in dataProvider).

Can someone please guide me on this.

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1:
In the customer model add this function:

```
Public function getCustomerContact(){
Return $this-> hasOne( CustomerContact::className,[customer_id,id]);

}
```

Then in your grid view you can easily reference the contact as follows:

```
customerContact.name
```

Note that this will only work if there is a one to one relationship between the tables

Option 2: (faster but more challenges)

In the data provider, use a query rather than a model ie $query = new \yii\db\Query();

You can then do all joins etc in the data provider. It is much faster but it requires a little more know-how

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by applying left-join in searchModel as following

```
$query = Customers::find();
$query->joinWith('customer-contact');
```

And also make hasOne relation with CustomerContact in Customer.php